# How to Attach a File to the Response On Page Render?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, popup, export, render

I'm getting the HTML results of my page load at the time of Rendering the page then attaching a pdf file to the browser:

```
 protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (isPdfExport)
        {
            var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            var htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
            base.Render(htmlWriter);
            var pageHtml = stringWriter.ToString();
            Write(GetBytes(pageHtml));
        }
        else
        {
            base.Render(writer);
        }
    }

    private void Write(byte[] bytes)
    {
        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=MyFile.pdf; size=" + bytes.Length.ToString());
        response.Flush();
        response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
    }
```

When the export button is clicked, it sets the isPdfExport field to true so that the Render method knows it should export.

The problem is that some binary data are rendered on the page whereas I expected to see a popup dialog containing the pdf file.

if the export happens on an event handler before Render, it works fine and brings a popup , however, I don't have access to the html data of the page at any time before Render event handler.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you used something like Firebug to verify that the content-type is being changed?  I suspect that the content-type is sent before the render event fires, and you can't change it once it's already been sent.

Comment: sorry, actually my code was absolutely fine; I was testing it by refreshing the page rather than a button click :P.

Answer (score 1):

Why not set up a .pdf handler, so all you have to do is provide a standard hyperlink to a .pdf file which would then prompt the popup to save the file?

e.g.

```
<a href="/Correspondence/12345.pdf">Download the PDF</a>
```

To do this, first you need to define a handler in `web.config` in the "Correspondence" subdirectory so that `.pdf` files are handled:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="*" path="*.pdf" type="PdfHandler"/>
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Then you write the handler itself, like this ought to do it:

```
Public Class PdfHandler
    Implements IHttpHandler

    Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable As Boolean Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler.IsReusable
        Get
            Return False
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpContext) Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
            If FileInvalid Then // Maybe want to check the path is valid, or they are authorised to see it, etc.
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404
                context.Response.StatusDescription = "404 Not Found"
                context.Response.Flush()
            Else
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=MyPDF.pdf")

                context.Response.BinaryWrite(PDFBinaryContent) // E.g. Loaded from a database, disk, etc                
            End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Finally just configure IIS to pass requests for .pdf to the .NET engine (don't forget to turn off 'Verify file exists' if appropriate. And that should do it.